# VSCode, typescript, eslint and prettier -> null check does not work

Tags: typescript, eslint, prettier

I've tried to setup typescript linting to use prettier and while prettier works, i seem to have lost the basic typescript error checking. How can i get this back?

[image]

^ should complain about accessing `.value` on `foo`?

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
}
```

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jasmine": true,
    "jest": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error", 
      { "singleQuote": true, "semi": false }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/class-name-casing":  ["error", { "allowUnderscorePrefix": true }],
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": ["error", { "prefixWithI": "always", "allowUnderscorePrefix": true}],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "args": "none"}],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "semi":"off"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
}
```

Comment: why `foo.value` should be error? `foo` is a object containing value as a variable, `logFoo(foo: {value: number | null})`

Comment: @PareshLomate The type of `foo` is `{value: number} | null`, so `foo` can be `null`.

Comment: yeah, i shouldn't be able to access `foo.value` if `foo === null`

Comment: Do you mean the `tsc` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `strictNullChecks` (or the more holistic `strict`, which includes `strictNullChecks`)? You don't have these in your config, if I enable above options, the compiler emits the error again.

Comment: write an answer and ill accept it this worked thank you